# Stored procedure is very slow on Crystal Report

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I am using SQL Anywhere as my database and Crystal Report for reporting purpose.

I have two tables `SALES DETAIL (POSDETAIL)` and `Inventory Adjusted table (AdjustInventory)` and creating and query to show sales and wastage/adjusted query.

Output should be like this

```
Product   SalesQty  Value    WastageQty    Value
------------------------------------------------
```

`Sales Qty` will come from `POSDETAIL` table and `WastageQty` will come from `AdjustInventory`

`POSDETAIL` has a total of 435625 records and `AdjustInventory` has 183528 total records.

I have designed below stored procedure it is giving me perfect output as needed and runs very fast in query analyzer, but on Crystal Reports using this stored procedure become very very slow it takes almost 15 to 25 minutes to display data on report for any date range.

```
Create PROCEDURE MyDatabaseTest.ReportUser.sp_SalesWastage ()
BEGIN
   DECLARE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE tblSumWastage (ProductId integer,TIMEORD  date,WastedQty integer);
   delete from  tblSumWastage;
   insert into tblSumWastage  

   select 
      DBA.AdjustInventory.INVENNUM as ProductId,
      DATEFORMAT(POSDETAIL.TIMEORD,'yyyy/mm/dd') as OrderDate,
      SUM(AdjustInventory.ADJUSTUNITS) as WastedQty
   from 
      DBA.POSDETAIL
   join 
      DBA.AdjustInventory on DBA.POSDETAIL.PRODNUM = DBA.AdjustInventory.INVENNUM
                             and DBA.AdjustInventory.AdjustType = 9 
                             and AdjustInventory.ADJUSTUNITS > 0 
                             and DATEFORMAT(DBA.AdjustInventory.AdjustTime,'yyyy/mm/dd') = DATEFORMAT(POSDETAIL.TIMEORD,'yyyy/mm/dd')
   group by 
       DBA.AdjustInventory.INVENNUM, DATEFORMAT(POSDETAIL.TIMEORD,'yyyy/mm/dd');

   select    
       p.OrderDate, p.ProductId, p.SalesQty, 
       f.WastedQty / p.SalesQty as WastedQty,
       p.EachCost
   from 
       (select 
           POSDETAIL.PRODNUM as ProductId,
           DATEFORMAT(POSDETAIL.TIMEORD,'yyyy/mm/dd') as OrderDate, 
           POSDETAIL.COSTEACH as EachCost,
           SUM(POSDETAIL.QUAN) as SalesQty
        from 
           DBA.POSDETAIL 
        group by 
           DATEFORMAT(POSDETAIL.TIMEORD,'yyyy/mm/dd'),
           POSDETAIL.PRODNUM,POSDETAIL.COSTEACH
       ) as p (ProductId, OrderDate, EachCost, SalesQty) 
   inner join 
       (select * from tblSumWastage) as f (ProductId, OrderDate, WastedQty) 
          on p.ProductId = f.ProductId and p.OrderDate = f.OrderDate;
END
```

Comment: statistics, indexes: rebuild.

Comment: All columns in Where clause and Group by are indexed, works perfect on query analyzer but on Crystal Report it is very very slow.

Comment: "works perfect on query analyzer but on Crystal Report it is very very slow." - Yes, I realise that from your question. Read my answer again: "statistics, indexes: rebuild. ".

Comment: May you please bit explain your answer? Thanks

Comment: Your query will ignore any waste that doesn't have a matching sale/order on the same date, is this what you want?  (I'm also assuming you can't get a total of `0` for `SalesQty`, otherwise you could hit a divide-by-zero error).  From the looks of it, you should be able to combine the two queries, which might help things some.  What RDBMS is backing this - does it have a `DATE()` function?  Formatting of dates is best left to the display layer.  No way you can get around using something like that if you're storing timestamps, though.

Comment: Yes, these are as per requirement and SalesQty can not be zero. Yes, time stamp is stored but not needed on report.

Answer (score 1):

The slowness might be in Crystal reports instead of in he stored procedure. For example if the stored procedure returns huge number of records and you filter them in the record selection formula. Another possible  reason could be if you have another table joined in the report with the result from the stored procedure. If the report looks OK then you can check the drivers and to play with different connection types - OLE DB, ODBC... I don't know what exactly is available for SQL Anywhere. 
Any chance to have this in a subreport , which is called multiple times ?

Comment: One way to test if the number of records is making Crystal slow is to limit the number of records being returned in the proc with a "Select TOP 10 ...."  This could be informative

Comment: No, this is not a sub report, I can not limit rows as user can query and date range.